# chrome console how to avoid stop which error happend position

Tags: google-chrome

If there are some errors which includes some error , then chrome debugger auto stop before error happend and wait for user's input to check the statement. But I want to make this settings invalid.Do you know how to avoid this settings?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript standard says that an application should stop executing once an unhandled exception has been reached. This means that you code raises an **Error** that is not **caught** in a try(){...}catch(){} block. Wrap your code in a try-catch block to get it to work

E.G:

```
function raiseError(){
  //...Error-raising code here
  throw new Error("Test Exception");
};

try{
  raiseError();
}
catch(e){
  console.log("Error caught", e);
}
```